# Find combinations with arrays and a combination pattern

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have arrays such as these, and each pattern designates a combination shape with each number representing the size of the combination.

- pattern 0: `[1, 1, 1, 1]`
- pattern 1: `[2, 1, 1]`
- pattern 2: `[3, 1]`
- pattern 3: `[4]`
- ...

I also have a char-valued list like below. len(chars) equals the sum of the upper array's value.

`chars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

I want to find all combinations of chars following a given pattern. For example, for pattern 1, 4C2 * 2C1 * 1C1 is the number of combinations.

```
[['A', 'B'], ['C'], ['D']]
[['A', 'B'], ['D'], ['C']]
[['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['D']]
[['A', 'C'], ['D'], ['B']]
[['A', 'D'], ['B'], ['C']]
[['A', 'D'], ['C'], ['B']]
...
```

But I don't know how to create such combination arrays. Of course I know there are a lot of useful functions for combinations in python. But I don't know how to use them to create a combination array of combinations.

**EDITED**

I'm so sorry my explanation is confusing. I show a simple example.

- pattern 0: `[1, 1]`
- pattern 1: `[2]`
- `chars = ['A', 'B']`

Then, the result should be like below. So first dimension should be permutation, but second dimension should be combination.

- pat0: `[['A'], ['B']]`
- pat0: `[['B'], ['A']]`
- pat1: `[['A', 'B']]  # NOTE: [['B', 'A']] is same in my problem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive function that takes the first number in pattern and generates all the combinations of that length from remaining items. Then recurse with remaining pattern & items and generated prefix. Once you have consumed all the numbers in pattern just `yield` the prefix all the way to caller:

```
from itertools import combinations

pattern = [2, 1, 1]
chars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

def patterns(shape, items, prefix=None):
    if not shape:
        yield prefix
        return

    prefix = prefix or []
    for comb in combinations(items, shape[0]):
        child_items = items[:]
        for char in comb:
            child_items.remove(char)
        yield from patterns(shape[1:], child_items, prefix + [comb])

for pat in patterns(pattern, chars):
    print(pat)
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('C',), ('D',)]
[('A', 'B'), ('D',), ('C',)]
[('A', 'C'), ('B',), ('D',)]
[('A', 'C'), ('D',), ('B',)]
[('A', 'D'), ('B',), ('C',)]
[('A', 'D'), ('C',), ('B',)]
[('B', 'C'), ('A',), ('D',)]
[('B', 'C'), ('D',), ('A',)]
[('B', 'D'), ('A',), ('C',)]
[('B', 'D'), ('C',), ('A',)]
[('C', 'D'), ('A',), ('B',)]
[('C', 'D'), ('B',), ('A',)]
```

Note that above works only with Python 3 since it's using `yield from`.

Comment: This is what I want to do! Thank you.